# Cambiar estilo de control al modificar una propiedad

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un control de usuario que es un boton, el control de usuario cuenta con algunas DependencyProperty, una de ellas es un enum, yo quiero lograr que se actualize el designer al cambiar el valor de la propiedad, por ejemplo que al seleccionar una opcion del enum en la definicion del designer que el designer cambie el boton de color.

Les dejo el codigo que tengo en mi XAML, el codigo del boton y el codigo del converter

```
xmlns:convertType="clr-namespace:Test.Converters">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <convertType:ConvertTypes x:Key="TypeToColorConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=ButtonControl, Mode=OneWay}"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Type, ElementName=ButtonControl, Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding Radius, ElementName=ButtonControl, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>

public partial class Btn : UserControl {

    public enum Types {
        Add,
        Delete,
        Modify
    }
    private static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Type), typeof(Types), typeof(Btn), new PropertyMetadata(Types.Add));
    public Types Type {
        get => (Types)GetValue(TypeProperty);
        set => SetValue(TypeProperty, value);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(Btn), new PropertyMetadata("Button"));
    public string Text {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Radius), typeof(int), typeof(Btn), new PropertyMetadata(10));
    public int Radius {
        get => (int)GetValue(RadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
    }

    public Btn() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class ConvertTypes : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        object result = Colors.Black;

        if (value is not null and Types b) {
            switch (b) {
                case Types.Add:
                    result = Colors.Green;
                    break;
                case Types.Delete:
                    result = Colors.Red;
                    break;
                case Types.Modify:
                    result = Colors.Blue;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: no deberia setearlo tu set?

Comment: Osea quiero utilizar el convverter, el problema esta en que al utulizarlo no me asigna el color en el xaml dejandome sin borde el boton, pero al hacer debug del converter esta devolviendo el color correcto. osea que no esta asignando bien el color al border solamente.